# Expo navigation without <Link>, but inside verification function

Tags: react-native, expo, navigation

I’m following the official expo documentation for navigating between pages.

https://docs.expo.dev/routing/navigating-pages/

However, what i’d like to accomplish is:
a) Perform validation on SignUp button press
b) After validation navigate to the new page

Does expo Navigation have equivalent of navigation.navigate()? I need to be able to call expo navigation from handleSubmitForm function instead of linking to another page right away.

> About

Comment: Look at "Imperative navigation" in the link you provided: https://docs.expo.dev/routing/navigating-pages/#imperative-navigation.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Will give it a try